# simple backbone example with rails api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, rest, backbone.js

So I created a rails api using rails-api gem. And I put my backbone code in the default public/index.html. I tried the json link and returns json, it's just a model called 'entry' with a single field called 'content' along with some default rails fields. But the backbone code doesn't work, could you spot any problem with this? I am just trying to show the list of records from the returned json.

```
// Models
window.Entry = Backbone.Model.extend();
window.EntryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Entry,
    url:"http://localhost:3000/entries"
});

// Views
window.EntryListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'ul',
    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (entry) {
            $(this.el).append("" + entry.get("content") + "");
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },
    list:function () {
        this.entryList = new EntryCollection();
        this.entryListView = new EntryListView({model:this.entryList});
        this.entryList.fetch();
        $('#entries').html(this.entryListView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: see this link = https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone and try this

Answer (score 0):

Can You check perhaps if /entries return 'results' node?
Perhaps You forgot to ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

In your AppRouter code, you have this line:

```
this.entryListView = new EntryListView({model:this.entryList});
```

However, entryList is a Collection, not a Model, so you have to define it like this:

```
this.entryListView = new EntryListView({collection:this.entryList});
```

Similarly, in your EntryListView code, you have:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);

...

_.each(this.model.models, function (entry) {
```

which should become:

```
this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);

...

_.each(this.collection.models, function (entry) {
```

I'm not sure if that is everything, but it's the only thing that is immediately apparent to me.

edit: added add'l change to this.model reference